# Registering an existing event handler with an object created via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, append

Ok, so I've got several objects which are basically the same with the exception of the text displayed on them. When they are clicked, perform an an action with an existing event handler

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="myclass">...<p>foo</p>...</div>
  <div class="myclass">...<p>bar</p>...</div>
  <div class="myclass">...<p>foo</p>...</div>
  ...etc etc
<div>
<div id="button" class="button">button-to-do-something</div>


$('.myclass').on('click', function () {
  ('this').css("background-color","red");
  //Some other junk happens here, but the red background is easily observed
});

$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').append('<div class="myclass">...<p>bar</p>...</div>');
});
```

I've set up a button that inserts another instance of the myclass div inside of the container div, however, when the dynamically created objects are clicked, they do nothing. The code, with the exception of the internal text (foo or bar in this instance) is exactly the same when observed with my browsers "inspect element". The event handler works for elements that are loaded with the page, but nothing happens for dynamically created objects.

Can I register the existing event handler for the dynamically inserted objects, or do I have to do something completely different?

Comment: Btw consider a template (e.g. Handlebars). HTML code hard coded inside JavaScript code is not a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delegate the event**

```
$(staticContainer).on('click', '.myClass' function () {
```

`staticContainer` is any container that is present in the DOM when the event is bound.

`Closest staticContainer` in your case might be `'#container'`

The closer it is to the element the better

Comment: +1 for using `staticContainer` rather than `document`.

Comment: Guarantee you the OP asks why `staticContainer` is `undefined`.

Comment: Nahh, got why it would have been undefined if I used it. Thanks for the answer though. =)

Answer (score 3):

You need to `delegate` it like so:

```
$('#container').on('click','.myclass', function () {
  ('this').css("background-color","red");
  //Some other junk happens here, but the red background is easily observed
});
```

**or**

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass', function () {
  ('this').css("background-color","red");
  //Some other junk happens here, but the red background is easily observed
});
```